# Is it possibly to queue dictionaries or lists in hashcat?

Tags: linux, command-line, luks, decryption, brute-force

I'm trying to brute force one of my old harddrives I no longer have the password for; (LUKS v1).

Hashcat is doing great for this, I'm just not sure how to queue multiple lists or dictionaries other that merging them all into a single list.

Ideally I would like to be able to start with the most likely lists, say, "keyboard patterns" or "common numbers" and then progress to other lists specified.

The current command is `hashcat -m 14600 -a 0 -w 3 luks-header <password>.txt -o found`, but I would like to specify more than .txt.

Something like: `hashcat -m 14600 -a 0 -w 3 luks-header <password>.txt, <dictionary>.txt, <numbers>.txt -o found`.

So that it will run those lists one after the other in the order specified. Is this possible?

I tried to Google it, but only found results for things with similar keywords even when I used "quotes".

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean like a shell script?

Comment: I was more wondering if hashcat itself had a way the function, like an option to input multiple lists in the command or how to specify it to do so. I could write a script I suppose :/ and that might not be a bad idea for convenience in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` loop for that.

This example will loop thru all .txt files in the current working directory and pass the name to hashcat as a variable:

```
for file in *.txt; do hashcat -m 14600 -a 0 -w 3 luks-header "$file" -o found; done
```